# Crash when process pixel after crop an image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing

After using this function to crop image:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.imageInput CGImage], rect);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

I bring "result" to use for process with pixel like that:

```
......

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

// Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
int byteIndex = 0;
for (NSInteger i = 0 ; i < width * height; i++) {
    int R = rawData[byteIndex];
    int G = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
    int B = rawData[byteIndex + 2];
    int test = [self getValueof:0.3* R + 0.59* G + 0.11 * B inRange:0 to:255];

    rawData[byteIndex] = (char)(test);
    rawData[byteIndex + 1] = (char)(test);
    rawData[byteIndex + 2] = (char)(test);
    byteIndex += 4;
}

ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                            CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                            8,
                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );
imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
free(rawData);
```

I will have crash? Anyone know about it, please help me.

update crash report: : copy_read_only: vm_copy failed: status 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long time find solution for this crash. I got an experience:
 - When process bitmap on iOS: if we don't notice orientation of image, maybe we got some strange crash.

With my crash above: I have fixed it very simple: change

```
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

by

```
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.imageInput.scale orientation:self.imageInput.imageOrientation];
```